# How to secure PDF files from download but allow it to View?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I want to integrate some kind of web based PDF viewer so that user can not download the PDF files but they can View them. This is for securing the PDF files from downloads. Something like scribd.com

See example here : [ref link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/27271539/Grameen-Bank-%E2%80%93-a-Case-Study)

Answer (score 0):

I used FlexPaper: [flexpaper.devaldi.com](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com)

This compile PDF in SWF, so is more protected.

Comment: is it mobile supported too?

Comment: apparently not. In my project is not necessary view in mobile, so it works well. Test [link](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/) to see how is show in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like [pdftohtml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/).

It is a tool based on the Xpdf package which translates PDF documents into HTML format.

You could use [Flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com), too, but it's free of charge only for open source projects...

Comment: Strage, it wortks, for me... This is a direct link to the software download: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pdftohtml/windows%20binary/pdftohtml-0.38%20win32/pdftohtml-0.38-win32.zip?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fpdftohtml%2F&ts=1395763662&use_mirror=cznic

Comment: Convert PDF in HTML provides more control, but is necessary implement a view to provide a better user usability.

Comment: You are right, of course... pdftohtml are two opposite approaches... The first requires much more work, but is much more flexible... I usually prefer this kind of attitude, but the choice is up to the OP... :-)